# How to set and replace j boss home page with application Login page

Tags: jboss7.x

I have removed j boss home but how to set my web application login page as J boss home page.so  when i click //localhost:8080/ my Application home page should open.
Please send the location of /context path so that i can set the path.
I am using jboss-as-7.1.1 version.
Thanku

Comment: I am facing problem only finding the boss-web.xml in j boss 7.1.1.final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

in jboss-web.xml in your WEB-INF folder in your web application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..But i m not finding jboss-web.xml in j boss 7.1.1.

Comment: @user1460514 finding? you have to create it. Like every other file.